# WSGI: _mysql.so Image not found

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, mysql-python

Environment: MacBook Pro, OSX 10.6, Python 2.6.1 64 bit, MySQL 5.X 64 bit

I am having problems installing MySQLdb for use with Django. After installing everything I am able to open the python interpreter and execute:

```
import MySQLdb
```

This works fine. I am also able to create and run django apps and host them using the development server:

```
./manage.py runserver
```

But I am now trying to host this django app in my local apache. So I installed and configured mod_wsgi and added a virtual host to httpd.conf setting the location of my *.wsgi script. From that script I am able to define the application function en return a simple Hello World string.

But when I try to run:

```
import MySQLdb
```

inside a try block in my *.wsgi script, the caught exception says the following:

```
dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: 
libmysqlclient.18.dylib Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_mysql.so 
Reason: image not found
```

So, simply put, the problem is that my MySQLdb adapter works when using it in the python interpreter and django development server, but not through Apache and mod_wsgi.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this path-> /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ accessible by Apache ?

Comment: *Does* that dylib exist?

Comment: Did you use Apple supplied Apache and Python or did you build your own? It can be important.

Comment: @Dantario How would i know if Apache can reach .../site-packages/?

Comment: @Ignacio Jip it exists. And I added the ENV var so it can be found.

Comment: @Graham Jip its the python and apache that came with the OSX. Should i rebuilt and install it from source. Arn't you the creator of mod_wsgi?

Comment: You can verify if Python can see that path by using 'import sys; print sys.path'. If its not there, you can always do 'import sys; sys.path.append('/some/other/path'). But, the error you're seeing may be related to building MySQL as one specific architecture when Apple's Python is universal - it can be goofy about linking to single-arch shared libs. To verify, run 'otool -l /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/_mysql.so' and see what its linked to, then run 'file <each dylib>' to see if they're universal or not.